# Jquery select with select?

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to select within a select (chaining) with my jQuery?

I basically have this, once i have cloned it, there are 2 more DIVs inside the new clone which I need to change as well using jQuery, these embedded divs have IDs, I could just put it on a new line and reselect using $

But thought jQuery allows chaining, but not show about select in an already selected jQuery expression.. here's my code

```
        var obligatoryElement = $('#obligatory-template').clone();

        $(obligatoryElement).attr('id', 'accessory-' + obligatory);

        $('#obligatory-template').after(obligatoryElement);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `find` method:

```
$('#some-element').find('a')
```